# jersey unit test with parameters error 500

Tags: unit-testing, servlets, get, jersey

I want to test a method with this declaration:

```
@GET
@Path("/hello")
public Response myMethod(@Context HttpServletRequest requestContext, 
                         @QueryParam("key") String value){...}

 Response output = target("/hello/myMethod")
                   .queryParam("key", "value")
                   .request().get();
```

but I get 500, internal server error, I know that it is because of the first parameter of my method (@Context HttpServletRequest requestContext) but I do not know how to solve it.

Comment: What are you using to test?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the Jersey test is not running inside a servlet environment, which is something that is required to work with the servlet APIs. If you are not aware, Jersey does not need to run inside a servlet container. If the case of using the provider-grizzly2, if you don't set up the test container, it will default to running the GrizzlyTestContainerFactory, which only starts Grizzly and an HTTP server, not a servlet container.

In order to configure the JerseyTest as a servlet container, we need to override two other methods, configurDeployment and getTestContainerFactory. With the latter, we need to return the GrizzlyWebTestContainerFactory, which will set up the servlet container. In the configureDeployment method, we can configure the application, at the servlet level.

public class ServletTest extends JersyTest {

```
@Override
public ResourceConfig configure() {
    // configure Jersey
}

@Override
public TestContainerFactory getTestContainerFactory() {
    return new GrizzlyWebTestContainerFactory();
}

@Override
public DeploymentContext configureDeployment() {
    return ServletDeploymentContext
            .forServlet(new ServletContainer(configure()))
            .build();
}
```

}

If you are using the provider-inmemory, it doesn't support servlet deployment, so you will need to switch over to the jetty provider or the grizzly provider.